# Given two hermitian matrices of signature (2,1) there exists a Cayley transform between them?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Given a matrix $A\in M_{k\times l}(\mathbb{C})$ we define the *hermitian transpose of $A$* as the matrix $A^*=\overline{A}^t\in M_{l\times k}(\mathbb{C})$. We say a matrix $H\in M_k(\mathbb{C})$ is *hermitian* if $H=H^*$. In particular, we can show easily that all eigenvalues of an hermitian matrix are real. We say that a $3\times 3$ hermitian matrix is of *signature (2,1)* if it has two positive eigenvalues and one negative eigenvalue. Given two hermitian matrices $H$ and $H'$, if $C$ is a matrix such that
$$H'=C^*HC,$$
we say $C$ is a *Cayley transform*.

I'm reading the [Notes on Complex Hyperbolic Geometry](https://www.icts.res.in/media/uploads/Program/Files/NCHG.pdf)
 by John Parker, and at the page 8 of it he says (at least it seems so) that if $H$ and $H'$ are hermitian matrices of signature (2,1) then such a $C$ always exists. Is that so? How can one show it?

I've tried to solve it by system of equations, but it's not so simple... :(

Answer (score 1):

This is a special case of [Sylvester's law of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia). By the way, the term Cayley transform usually refers to [something else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_transform).